condition of banach space in Proposition 3.13 brezis
Let $\sigma(E^*,E)$ the weak-* topology in $E^*$ and $(f_n) \in E^*$ a sequence. Then
If $f_n \rightharpoonup^* f \implies (||f_n||)$ bounded, and $||f|| \leq \liminf |||f_n||$.
we can use that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x \in E$, this implies that $|f_n(x)|$is bounded for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by a number $M_x \in \mathbb{R}.$ If we denote $B^*$ the set of $f_n$ using a dual corollary of uniform bounded principle we finish with that $B^*$ its bounded. But this use that the space it is banach.
I know that $E^*$ is banach, but if I consider $B$ the set of $f_n$ I would have to show for all $h \in E^{**}$ that $h(f_n)$ its bounded, fixing $n.$
we can do it without use that $E$ is banach?

The result is wrong if $E$ is not Banach.

The result is not true in incomplete normed spaces. Take $X=c_{00}$, the space of sequences with finite support, and define $f_n \colon X \to \mathbb R$ via
$$(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_N, 0 ,\dots ) \mapsto n x_n .$$
Then $f_n(x) \to 0$ for every $x \in c_{00}$, i.e., $f_n \to 0$ weak-star, but $\|f_n\|=n \to +\infty$.
